# jqm navbar button clicked when pressing Android soft keyboard 'Next' key if form field is underneath navbar

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

We have a troubling issue with a nav bar button being triggered when a user 'tabs' between edit field using the Android soft keyboard's 'Next' key.  This appears to be limited to Android 4.1 as the issue does not appear on Android 4.0.  We are using Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7" devices and do not have access at this time to any other Andorid devices to compare.  We are using jQuery v1.8.2 with jQuery Mobile v1.2.0.  jQM 1.3 is not an option for us at this time, due to other dependant libraries in our project that don't support jQM 1.3 at this time.

The following code can be used to reproduce the behaviour if viewed from the device browser;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style>
            body {font-size:14px;}
            .my-ui-header > .ui-btn {margin: 10px; height: 3.7em; width: 5.3em;}
            .my-ui-header .ui-btn-inner {padding-top:1.65em; padding-bottom:1.65em; }
            .ui-header .my-title {font-size: 32px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left: 3em; margin-right: 2em;text-align: center; overflow: hidden;}
            .ui-header .my-subtitle {font-size: 18px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 4em; margin-right: 2em; text-align: center; overflow: hidden;}
            .footer-nav .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner {padding-top: 40px !important;}
            .footer-nav .ui-btn .ui-icon { width: 30px!important; height: 30px!important; margin-left: -15px !important; box-shadow: none!important; -moz-box-shadow: none!important; -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;-webkit-border-radius: 0 !important; border-radius: 0 !important; background-size: 30px 30px;}            
        </style>        
        <title>JQM Fixed Footer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#home').live('pageinit', function() {
                    $("#button1").bind("click", function(event, ui) {
                        alert("Oy...button 1 was clicked!");
                    });
                    $("#button2").bind("click", function(event, ui) {
                        alert("Oy...the other button was clicked,\nyeah,button 2 it was!");
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" class="my-ui-header">
                <p class="my-title">DEMO TITLE</p>
                <p class="my-subtitle">Subtitle</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="dateField">Date</label>
                    <input id="dateField" name="dateField" type="date" name="clear" id="dateField" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="timeField">Time</label>
                    <input id="timeField" name="timeField" type="time" name="clear" data-clear-btn="true" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="Item1Select">Item 1</label>
                    <input id="Item1Select" name="Item1Select" type="text" name="clear" data-clear-btn="true" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="obsobs" >Item 2</label>
                    <input id="obsobs" name="obsobs" type="number" name="clear" data-clear-btn="true" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="item3" >Item 3</label>
                    <input id="item3" name="item3" type="number" name="clear" data-clear-btn="true" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="item4">Item 4</label>
                    <input id="item4" name="item4" type="number" name="clear" data-clear-btn="true" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="item5" >Item 5</label>
                    <input id="item5" name="item5" type="number" name="clear" data-clear-btn="true" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="item6">Item 6</label>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="item6" id="item6"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="item7">Item 7</label>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="item7" id="item7"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="item8" >Item 5</label>
                    <input id="item8" name="item8" type="number" name="clear" data-clear-btn="true" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-id="oneFooter">
                <div data-role="navbar" class="footer-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" id="button1" data-icon="custom">Button 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="button2" data-icon="custom">Button 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Our project is based on Cordova and so this is appearing on the stock browser.  I created a jsFiddle for the above code here (http://jsfiddle.net/UMm3c/11) that can be used to observe the behaviour.  To see this issue in action, scroll the page down and select the second edit box of the top row under the Col 2. label.  The soft keyboard appears.  While the keyboard is visible, scroll the page down so the second row of edit boxes are covered by the keyboard (if not already).  Then tap the keyboard 'Next' button.  Depending on your orientation, you will get an alert that indicates one of the nav bar buttons has been pressed.  The soft keyboard will disappear, and focus will be on the first edit box of the second row.  In fact, you can cause it to occur by trying to 'tab' to any field element that is directly under the nav bar when the soft keyboard is visible.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong in the page setup that causes this behaviour?  Is there anything that I can do to resolve this?

If you have read this far, thank you for sticking with it, and thanks for any and all help.

Alex.